# Backup all from my E-commerce (Magento)

Tags: backup, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, snapshot

I have a VM instances located on Google Cloud Compute Engine custom (6 vCPUs, 32 GB memory)Intel Sandy Bridge which use Debian. It's an E-commerce on Magento 1.9.3
If I want to create a full backup of my website in case the website break. How can I do it?
The full backup should have files, configuration server, Database, order info, etc.
Thanks.
Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a backup of your VM instance which includes your E-commerce (Magento) and have the VM backup include files, configuration files, databases in the VM disk, orders info, etc, you can create a snapshot of your VM as per the following [snapshot documentation link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots).
This documentation will guide you to create a snapshot backup of your instance persistent disk which will include the VM instance configuration file and database if hosted locally, depending on your configuration.

To create a snapshot:

1. At the Google Cloud Platform click on Products & Services which is the icon with the four bars at the top left hand corner.
2. On the menu go to the Compute section and hover on Compute Engine and then click on Snapshots.
3. At the menu above click on CREATE SNAPSHOT
4. At the ‘Create a snapshot’ page fill in all the required information and choose the correct disk for your VM Instance.
5. Click on create a snapshot and wait until the snapshot is created.

The first snapshot that is created is a full backup of all your data in the VM boot disk. Any further backups contain any new data or modified data since the first successful snapshot.

It would be very important that you follow the recommendations and instruction in the above [documentation link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots) to ensure that your snapshot is successful.

It is also important to check and test that this backup is correct and check that you can recreate your systems from it should a disaster occur.

Comment: Hi JMD! Thanks for your reply. I created the Snapshot as you mention. Them I created a new instances to check the backup. I noticed that when I copy and paste the IP Address of the new VM instance it redirects to the old instances. This is an example: the instances that I made the backup is www.mywebsite.com and the new instances that I created using the Snapshot redirect to www.mywebsite.com and not the IP Address that the new VM instances has. Why?

Comment: You can try accessing the new VM using its IP address instead, for testing purposes. Both VMs should have different external IPs.

Comment: Yes, it has different address but when I testing the new IP address it redirect to VM from where I took the Snapshot. It can be something related to the cache on the server?

Comment: This should not be happening. How do you know you're connected to the old VM instance (the one you took the snapshot from) and not to the new one? Have you connected via the browser?

Comment: Because when I test the new IP address I see a redirect 301 to the old VM. I checked the .htaccess and I didn't see any redirect. It's something out of mind! I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to create a snapshot of the disk of your magneto instance.

You can do it by running the following command:

```
gcloud compute disks snapshot [DISK_NAME]
```

In addition, I'm attaching you the documentation of [snapshot in GCP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots#creating_snapshots)